Probability of winning for each player in turn-based game (single attempt and known probabilities)
I have a turn-based game in which each player $A, B, \ldots, n$ has a known probability of winning $p_A, p_B, \ldots, p_n$ on their turn and in which each player has a single attempt at winning. That means that (assuming all $p < 1$) there is a chance of no player winning. In my case, the playing order is chosen randomly, but as I am interested in a general case this constraint can probably be removed (edit: edited to avoid unneeded complication).
The simplest case with two players would look like this:
Example of two-players case
I can calculate the probability of no player winning in the general case by:
$$P(\text{nobody wins}) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1-p_i)$$
And, while I know how to calculate "by hand" the winning probability of a player, as a non-math person I am struggling to wrap my head around how to write a general equation for it.
I have a feeling there must be a way to partition the probability of any player winning.
$$P(\text{somebody wins}) = 1 - P(\text{nobody wins})$$
among the different players, but I cannot figure out how.
Other than a solution, I would welcome any pointer towards the study of this kind of case if they have a name (I could not figure out what to google for... heck I cannot even figure out what tags to use for this question).
Extra point: as I am trying to run simulations under different cases, any other pointer towards computation-efficient methods (i.e. not having to run nested for loops) would be extremely appreciated.

With more than two players, what is the format ? Each player plays against each player (round robin) or knockout or what ?Pl specify exact format. On my turn whom do I play ? If I lose, do I play again with someone else ? Etc etc

The format is not a series of 1v1 matches, the players are not playing against each other. Each player, sequentially, has a single attempt at winning. The order of playing is selected randomly. If a player wins, following players do not get to play.
In a three player format, each player has 1/3 probability of going first, if the first player does not win, each of the two remaining player has a 1/2 probability of going second, and so on.
3 player case (partial)

I am  giving a solution to the $3$ person game.
Firstly, instead of initially naming the players, A,B,C, name the players F,S,T (for First to get chance, Second to get chance, Third to get chance to play with probabiities of winning (given chance) being $f,s,t$ respectively irrespective of when they are given chance
Then $P(F)\; wins)\; = \frac13f \tag1$
$P(F\; loses)\; = \frac13(1-f) \tag2$
$P(S\; wins)\; = \frac13(1-f)\frac12s = \frac16(1-f)s \tag3$
$P(S\; loses)\; =\frac16(1-f)(1-s)\tag4$
$P(T\;wins)\;=\frac16(1-f)(1-s)t \tag5$
$P(T\; loses)\; = \frac16(1-f)(1-s)(1-t)\tag6$
Now since there is symmetry in $A,B,C$ being the first, second or third to play, we can derive whatever result we want from these equations, e.g.
$P(A\, wins) = [Eq.(1) + Eq.(3) + Eq(5)]/3$
$P(All\; lose) = Eq (6)$
Other combos of results can be easily derived using the above equations.

If player $k$ has probability $p_k$ of winning given that he gets an attempt, then

player $1$ wins with probability $p_1$,
player $2$ wins with probability $p_2(1-p_1)$,
player $3$ wins with probability $p_3(1-p_2)(1-p_1)$,
and so on.

Formally, player $p_k$ will be the winner with probability $p_k \prod_{j < k}(1-p_j)$.  Note that if you have $n$ players, you don't really need to consider "nobody wins" as a special case... just add a final, dummy player, and give him $p_{n+1}=1$.

You have taken that player 1,2, 3 play in that order sequentially, but OP in their clarification in comments has specifically written "The order of playing is selected randomly." There is also a clause that "If a player wins, following players do not get to play" I hope you haven't given a downvote because these clauses have made my answer more complex ! Regards

I haven’t given a downvote… the general answer with random move order is definitely more complex!

Ok,  fine, I just asked because you made different assumptions. $;;$ :)

The question is a bit vague.... in the first paragraph, it says, "In my case, the playing order is chosen randomly, but as I am interested in a general case this constraint can probably be removed."  So I removed it.  I'd be interested if there's a nice general form for the random-order answer... it looks like a bit of a mess.

My apologies, I meant to say that, rather than $n!$ permutations of playing order all equally likely to occur, some permutations could be more likely to occur depending on another parameter of the player. However, as that was not my specific case and I believe it complicates things excessively, I will edit that out.

Alternative syntax to the general problem.
Index the players Player-1, Player-2, ..., Player-n.
Assume that Player-i's probability of winning, if it is their turn, is $~p_i.$
Let $~q_i~$ denote $~1 - p_i.$
Assume that the order in which the players take their turns is randomized.
Let $~f(k,i)~$ denote the probability that none of the players that precede Player-i win, assuming that Player-i is the $~k$-th player to take a turn.
With $~k~$ varying from $~1~$ through $~n,~$ there is a $~\dfrac{1}{n}~$ probability of  Player-i being the $~k$-th player to take their turn.
So, Player-i's probability of winning is
$$\frac{1}{n} \times \sum_{k=1}^n \left[ ~f(k,i) ~p_i ~\right].$$
Then, since there are $~\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{k-1}~$ ways of (randomly) selecting the $~k-1~$ players who precede Player-i, $~f(k,i)~$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{k-1}~$ terms:
$$f(k,i) = \frac{1}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}} \sum_{1 \leq j_1 < j_2 < \cdots < j_{k-1} \leq n} \left[ q_{j_1} \times q_{j_2} \times \cdots \times q_{j_{k-1}} ~\right]. \tag1 $$
In (1) above, it is assumed that:

None of $~j_1, ~j_2, ~\cdots, ~j_{k-1}~$ equals $~i.~$

If $~k = 1,~$ then $~f(k,i) = f(1,i) = 1.$



Although some valid answers were provided for restricted cases, a general answer is still missing. I worked a little further on that and I reached a working solution. This might not be the best solution, but lacking anything better I will answer my own question. Mind that I am unsure if further simplification is possible. Moreover, since it still does not answer the question on if $$P(\text{somebody wins})=1−P(\text{nobody wins})$$ can be partitioned among the $n$ players based on their $p_n$, I will keep the question open.
Answer
For a set of players $\Bbb{G} = \{G_1, G_2, \dots, G_n\}$ of size $n$,
let $\Bbb{P} = \{p_{G_1}, p_{G_2}, \dots, p_{G_n}\}$ be the set of their respective probabilities of winning comes their turn.
For any one player $G_i$, let $P(G_i)$ be their overall probability of winning the game and define
$$\Bbb{G'} = \Bbb{G} \setminus \{G_i\}$$
and
$$\Bbb{P'} = \Bbb{P} \setminus \{p_{G_i}\}$$
then
$$P(G_i) = \frac{p_{G_i} \cdot \left( 1 + \prod_{k \in \Bbb{P'}}(1-k) \right)}{n} + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}\left((n-1-j)! \cdot j! \cdot \sum_{\Bbb{X}\in\left(\begin{matrix} \Bbb{P'} \\ j \end{matrix}\right)}\left(\prod_{x\in\Bbb{X}}(1-x)\right)\cdot p_{G_i} \right)}{n!} \tag{1}$$
Explanation
For $n$ players, there are $n!$ possible permutations of the playing order. $P(G_i)$ is equal to the sum of all the single probabilities of winning in each permutation divided by the number of permutations. I made the distinction between three main cases: $G_i$ goes first, $G_i$ goes last, $G_i$ goes anywhere between second and second to last.
$G_i$ goes first
If $G_i$ goes first, their probability of winning is $p_{G_i}$. As such,the contribution to $P(G_i)$ of a permutation in which $G_i$ is first is $p_{G_i}/n!$.
As there are $(n-1)!$ permutations in which $G_i$ plays first, the sum of their contribution to $P(G_i)$ is $$\frac{(n-1)! \cdot p_{G_i}}{n!}$$ that can be simplified to
$$\frac{p_{G_i}}{n} \tag{2}$$
$G_i$ goes last
If $G_i$ goes last, their probability of winning is
$$\prod_{k \in \Bbb{P'}}(1-k) \cdot p_{G_i}$$
Similarly to above, this situation occurs $(n-1)!$ times and their overall contribution to $P(G_i)$ is:
$$\frac{(n-1)! \cdot \prod_{k \in \Bbb{P'}}(1-k) \cdot p_{G_i}}{n!}$$
which is simplified to
$$\frac{\prod_{k \in \Bbb{P'}}(1-k) \cdot p_{G_i}}{n} \tag{3}$$
$G_i$ goes anywhere in between
This is the hardest bit and I used some set notation to help me out.
Let $\Bbb{Z}$ be the subset of $\Bbb{G'}$ of size $j$ of players that are in turn order before $G_i$, and let $\Bbb{X}$ their probability of winning comes their turn, then
$$ \Bbb{X}\in\left(\begin{matrix} \Bbb{P'} \\ j \end{matrix}\right) $$
The contribution to $P(G_i)$ for a case with $\Bbb{Z}$:
$$\frac{\prod_{x\in\Bbb{X}}(1-x)\cdot p_{G_i}}{n!}$$
The set $\Bbb{Z}$ can have $j!$ different permutations, each of which can occur $(n-1-j)!$ (the number of permutations of players playing after $G_i$) times.
As such, the overall contribution of $\Bbb{Z}$ to $P(G_i)$ is
$$\frac{(n-1-j)! \cdot j! \cdot \sum_{\Bbb{X}\in\left(\begin{matrix} \Bbb{P'} \\ j \end{matrix}\right)}\left(\prod_{x\in\Bbb{X}}(1-x)\right)\cdot p_{G_i}}{n!}$$
and to account for all possible values of $j$:
$$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}\left((n-1-j)! \cdot j! \cdot \sum_{\Bbb{X}\in\left(\begin{matrix} \Bbb{P'} \\ j \end{matrix}\right)}\left(\prod_{x\in\Bbb{X}}(1-x)\right)\cdot p_{G_i} \right)}{n!} \tag{4}$$
Note that $j$ goes from $1$ to $n-2$ because the cases of $j = 0$ (no players are in order before $G_i$) and $j = n-1$ (all other players are in order before $G_i$) have been already considered above.
Sum all
$Eq.(2)$ and $Eq.(3)$ can be put together:
$$\frac{p_{G_i} \cdot \left( 1 + \prod_{k \in \Bbb{P'}}(1-k) \right)}{n} \tag{5}$$
and now
$$Eq.(1) = Eq.(5) + Eq.(4)$$

My answer gives a general solution.
